# CSS :after & :before acting very strangely

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Ok, so I have a simple div with a height and width set.
Before and after also have height and width set.
They are all set to display as blocks, and the pseudo-elements have content "".

The :before is inside the content, not before it.
And the :after has a load of weird spacing before it.

HTML:

```
<div class="board">
   Hi
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.board {
  width: 260px; /*300 - 40*/
  height: 400px; /*480 - 40 - 40*/
  line-height: 400px;
  color: #164d87;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background:
    linear-gradient( 0deg,
      rgba(2, 188, 226, 0.5) 0%,
      rgba(51, 219, 253, 0.5) 25%,
      rgba(51, 219, 253, 0.5) 75%,
      rgba(2, 188, 226, 0.5) 100%
    );
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid #2B2B2B;
}
.board:before, .board:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/MattCowley/pen/ZOQMNg

Comment: The problem might be the large line-height value, what are these :before and :after for anyway?

Comment: What is your actual question? ... and the space before `:after` is caused by the `line-height`

Comment: @LGSon Why is the :before displaying inside the main div? Any why is the line-height effecting it, as the line-height is the same height as the div?

Comment: Because this is how ::before works as per specification: _::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the element matched._ [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

Comment: The `:before` is a block and push the content down, the `:after` is too, hense again break the line after the content, so the behavior is same as using inner div's. If you set background color on them you'll see how they behave ... elaborate with the display and height and again you'll see their behavior

Comment: @raphv So how do I make it display before the div as a block.

Comment: equal the height and line-height of pseudo-elements

Comment: "Before the div" you can't that way don't work pseudo-elements ... will be "before" the content of the div itself ...

Comment: You need to make an extra element inside the div if you want the pseudos out of the box http://codepen.io/anon/pen/beEmgz

Comment: Thanks @DaniP for that!

Comment: @DaniP, that you should write as an answer. From [W3C](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-elements/:before) wiki ---> The ::before pseudo-element can be used to describe generated content before an element's **content.**

Answer (score 0):

To keep existing markup, you can use `position: absolute`, and if you need the div to adjust to surrounding elements, give it a left/right margin matching the pseudo's width.

```css
.board {
  position: relative;
  width: 260px; /*300 - 40*/
  height: 400px; /*480 - 40 - 40*/
  line-height: 400px;
  color: #164d87;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  background:
    linear-gradient( 0deg,
      rgba(2, 188, 226, 0.5) 0%,
      rgba(51, 219, 253, 0.5) 25%,
      rgba(51, 219, 253, 0.5) 75%,
      rgba(2, 188, 226, 0.5) 100%
    );
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid #2B2B2B;
}
.board:before, .board:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.board:before, .board:after {
  bottom: calc(100% + 3px);      /*  3px for the border  */
}
.board:after {
  top: calc(100% + 3px);
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
   Hi
</div>
```